# Вид предложения

Tags: синтаксис

*Эти тропы первый раз разделились: одна пошла вверх по течению, другая - куда-то вправо.*

Данное предложение сложное бессоюзное или с разными видами связи ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это предложение сложное бессоюзное. Состоит из трёх простых предложений. Вторая  часть состоит из двух однородных простых предложений, раскрывающих содержание первой части. Между предложениями связь интонационная, бессоюзная.